# Regular Expressions, getting digit after second occurence of dot

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I want to get a number after second dot in a string like that :
**4.5.3. Some kind of question ?**  but input string might look like this as well **41.53.32. Some kind of question ?** so im aiming for **3** in the first example and **32** in second example.

I'm trying to do it with

```
(?<=(\.\d\.))[0-9]+
```

and it works on 1st example, but when im trying to add `(?<=(\.\d+\.))[0-9]+`
it doesn't work at all.

Comment: What language or tool are you using ? and is there always a dot after the final number ?

Comment: Are number sizes limited to 2 digits? Is there ever any text between the target and the end of input other than a dot?

Comment: You should clarify what language you are using, as there are differences between regex based on language. Regex is fairly standard, but not all languages use Regex the same way, so keep that in mind when asking questions.

Comment: Positive lookbehind `(?<=...)` have to be fixed size, so `\d+` will not work there. Use a non-matching group instead: `(?:...)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If there is always a dot after the final number then you can use the following expression:

```
\d+(?=\.(?:[^\d]|$))
```

This will match one or more digits `\d+` which are followed by a dot `.` then something that is either not a number `[^\d]` of the end-of-string `$`, i.e. `(?=\.(?:[^\d]|$))`.

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gQ3nA3)

Answer (score -1):

```
(?:(?:.*\.)?){2}(\d+)
```

the following regex should work for your use case.

check it out **[here](http://regex101.com/r/zW8vA1)**

Comment: This won't work because `.*` matches dots too, so it would consume several dots if they appeared before a dot. Try `.*?` instead

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/zW8vA1 i made changes to the regex this seems to be working fine

Comment: It wouldn't work with `1.2.3.4.5.6.`. It should pick 3, but your regex would pick 6. The question asks to match the number after the second dot. Your regex matches the last number as long as at least two dots appear before it, which is not correct

Answer (score -1):

If you use PERL or PHP, you can try this pattern:

```
(?:\d+\.){2}\K\d+
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(\d+.\d+.)\K\d+
```

Match digits dot digits dot digits, with the first section as a group not selected.

Comment: No need for a downvote, this does exactly as asked. http://rubular.com/r/V5cRQL84Fj

Answer (score -1):

The simplest complete answer is probably something like this:

```
(?<=^(?:[^.]*\.){2})\d+
```

If you're at all worried about performance, this one will be slightly faster:

```
^(?:[^.]*\.){2}(\d+)
```

This one will capture the desired value in capturing group 1.

If you are using an engine that doesn't support variable-length lookbehind, you'll need to use the second version.

If you wish, you can replace `[^.]` with `\d`, to only match digits.